# PHP + CodeIgniter foreach loop show each list items while only showing list title once if user has permission to see such option

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, permissions

I'm using codeigniter and I have a situation where I have a user's specific array of permissions to specific links defined in a variable inside My_Controller.php. I also have a multidimensional array of links specified in the config file (application/config). Now what is required is to loop through the permissions comparing them against the links array and printing out only those links that the user has permissions to while grouping the links according to their titles as defined in the config file. I have managed to loop through but the problem is that it displays the title after each option instead of printing the title once with a list of links under it. I checked through a similar problem and found out that the solution approach is the same but the problem comes where I have to loop through the permissions array which means I have three nested loops instead of two. Also is there any performance trade-off in having three nested loops?

This is the expected output;

**Manage**

```
Users
Edit Users
Reception
```

**Tools**

```
Settings
Edit Settings
```

This is what I'm getting;

**Manage**

```
Users
```

**Manage**

```
Edit Users
```

**Manage**

```
Reception
```

**Tools**

```
Settings
```

**Tools**

```
Edit Settings
```

Here is the config file:

```
$config['nav']['manage'] = array(
    'users' => 'auth_title_users',
    'users/edit' => 'auth_title_users_edit',
    'reception' => 'auth_title_reception'
);

$config['nav']['tools'] = array(
    'settings' => 'auth_title_settings',
    'settings/edit' => 'auth_title_settings_edit'
);
```

Here's the code in my header.php (application/views/includes);

```
// $navs contains the multidimentional array of the defined links according to the config file
$navs = $this->config->item('nav', 'tank_auth');

// $menu_items is the array containing permissions the user has from the db
foreach($menu_items as $menu_item){ 
    $val = $menu_item;

    if($navs){
    foreach($navs as $k => $v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            $header_written = FALSE;
            foreach($v as $key => $value){
                // compare permissions against the links
                if($val == $key){   
                    if (!$header_written){
                        $section_hr = lang('auth_section_'.$k);
                        echo "\t<h3>".$section_hr."</h3>\n";
                    }
                    $list_item = lang('auth_title_'.$key);
                    echo "\t<ul>\n";
                    echo "\t\t<li>".$list_item."</li>\n";
                    $header_written = TRUE;
                }           
            } 
        }
        else{
            $header_written = FALSE;
        }       
        if ($header_written){
            echo "\t</ul>\n";
        }    
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use in_array instead of looping through permissions the user have that will let you remove your most outer foreach statement.

```
if ( in_array($key, $menu_items) ) # instead of if($val == $key){
```